# Update a Column of a Record Based on the Column of a Duplicate Record

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find duplicate rows based on column A, in a table, that have different data for column B. Then I need to update column B so it has the same data, based soley on > than zero data. If one record has column B = 0000, and the other record has column B = 1234, then UPDATE the first record column B to 1234.  Find records with same Card#, if ID is zero for one of the records, UPDATE it to match the other record.

Comment: Please show what you have already tried

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can't have an `UPDATE` that also retrieves data from the same table, so you'll have to make a copy of the other data in a temporary table (or go about this in a completely different way).

So something like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE duplicate_ids AS (
    SELECT card_number, id
    FROM the_table AS t1
    INNER JOIN the_table AS t2 ON (t1.card_number = t2.card_number and t2.id > t1.id)
    WHERE t1.id = '0000'
);

UPDATE the_table 
INNER JOIN duplicate_ids ON the_table.card_number = duplicate_ids.card_number
SET the_table.id = duplicate_ids.id;
```

Presumably you'd do this within a transaction.

As an aside, if you have control over the database schema, you should eliminate the possibility of this type of duplication occurring. If your table can have more than one instance of the same card number, but the ID is supposed to be the same everywhere, you need two tables:

1. The one you have now, but without the ID column
2. A new table that just has `(card_number, ID)`

Then in any query where you need the ID number, you can get it from that other table with a `JOIN`. This way it's completely impossible to have two different numbers on file for the same card; there's one and only one place to record that number, even if the card has more than one record.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as:

```
update t join
       (select t.cardnum, max(b) as maxb
        from t
        group by t.cardnum
        having count(distinct b) > 1
       ) tt
       on t.cardnum = tt.cardnum
    set t.b = tt.maxb
    where t.b <> tt.maxb;
```

The subquery gets the substitution value.  The `having` clause makes sure there are actual duplicates.